# react native DrawerLayoutAndroid background colour not working

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a drawingLayout which is white and opacity is 50%.

So I copied the code from the docs and wrote

```
<DrawerLayoutAndroid
  drawerWidth={200}
  drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
  renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}
  drawerBackgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)">
```

But the drawer comes out full opacity white

I then tried just to experiment to see what happens if i make it black

```
<DrawerLayoutAndroid
  drawerWidth={200}
  drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
  renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}
  drawerBackgroundColor="rgba(255,255,255,1)">
```

but it still came out white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the style in your navigationView. Change the background color of the container in navigationView.

```
    var DrawerExample = React.createClass({

        render: function() {
            var navigationView = (
                <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'}}>
                    <Text style={{margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'left'}}>I'm in the Drawer!</Text>

                </View>
            );
            return (
                <DrawerLayoutAndroid
                    drawerWidth={300}
                    drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
                    renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}>
                    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center'}}>
                        <Text style={{margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'right'}}>Hello</Text>
                        <Text style={{margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'right'}}>World!</Text>

                    </View>
                </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
            );
        },
    });
```

Comment: I tried that and although the colour changed the opacity change never worked

Comment: Sorry I don't understand does this go in the render part or the return part?

Comment: You have created your navigation view. Right? In that view you have taken a container. Change the style of that container.

Comment: I have copied the docs, so I have a section in render and then the drawerlayout in in return, inside drawerlayout I have my main View